# Create line after text with css doesn`t work

Tags: html, css

Someone is able to solve my problem why it doesn't work?
It is possible to make a double line?
When I remove card-info, card, card-container everything works

```
.card-content h2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
 }

.card-content h2::after {
   content: '';
   flex: 1;
   margin-left: 1rem;
   height: 1px;
   background-color: #000;
 }
```

```css
.card-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 6rem 0 3rem 0;
}

.card-info h1 {
  font-family: 'Vollkorn';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #CDAA7C;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.column-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.card-content {
  padding-left: 0.6rem;
}

.card-content h2 {
  font-family: 'Vollkorn';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 21.8776px;
  color: #222222;
}

.card-content p {
  font-family: 'Vollkorn';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 21.8776px;
  color: #999999;
}

.card-content h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-content h2::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-info">
  <h1>Nasze usługi</h1>
</div>

<div class="card-container">
  <div class="column-left">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/Ellipse 28.png" alt="" class="card-img">

      <div class="card-content">
        <h2>Placek po zbójnicku</h4>
          <p>12.05.2023</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/Ellipse 28.png" alt="" class="card-img">

      <div class="card-content">
        <h2>Placek po zbójnicku</h4>
          <p>12.05.2023</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/Ellipse 28.png" alt="" class="card-img">

      <div class="card-content">
        <h2>Placek po zbójnicku</h4>
          <p>12.05.2023</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/Ellipse 28.png" alt="" class="card-img">

      <div class="card-content">
        <h2 class="">Placek po zbójnicku </h4>
          <p>12.05.2023</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/Ellipse 28.png" alt="" class="card-img">

      <div class="card-content">
        <h2>Placek po zbójnicku</h4>
          <p>12.05.2023</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="./img/Ellipse 28.png" alt="" class="card-img">

      <div class="card-content">
        <h2>Placek po zbójnicku</h4>
          <p>12.05.2023</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set a width for .card-content h2::after.

For example:

```
.card-content h2::after {
   content: '';
   flex: 1;
   margin-left: 1rem;
   width: 10px;
   height: 1px;
   background-color: #000;
 }
```